# Python converting negative float64 values to dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I am having trouble I have two date columns which both come in as a float64 dtype. The file I am pulling from is a sas7bdat file and I am having trouble with some of the values primarily the values that come in as negative.

So for example my values look like such: -21914 and my positive values look like this 20797. I am using the following code right now which seems to be converting the positive values just fine but has a problem with the negative values for some reason.

```
df['DATE'] = (df['DATE'])
df['DATE'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['DATE'], unit='D') + pd.Timestamp('1960-1-1')
df['DATE'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format='%d%b%Y')
```

Like I noted above this converts the positive values just fine, but the negative values it gives me the same date for each of them even though some of the negative values are different. I thought it may be a problem with the negative sign so I changed my code up and started using this.

```
df['DATE'] = abs(df['DATE'])
df['DATE'] = (df['DATE'])
df['DATE'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['DATE'], unit='D') + pd.Timestamp('1960-1-1')
df['DATE'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format='%d%b%Y')
```

I turned all of the float64 values into absolute values which would turn the negative values to positive and I got a different date for the negative values which are now positive, but all of those dates are still exactly the same like they were when they were negative. I am up for suggestions at this point since I cant seem to get past this slight problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with a `df` like this: `df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': [-21914, 20797, -21915]})`. It gives me different dates for the negative values (first and last). Am I missing something?

Comment: `pd.to_timedelta(df['DATE'], unit='D') + pd.Timestamp('1960-1-1')` should be a `Timestamp` already. Why then the `pd.to_datetime` afterwards?

Comment: Can you post the output of `df['Date']` so we can know where exactly the date is same ?

Answer (score 0):

Post the output of this simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.array([-10.0, -5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 10.0])

df = pd.DataFrame(x, index=range(0,10,2), columns=['DATE'])

df['DATE'] = (df['DATE'])

df['DATE'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['DATE'], unit='D') + pd.Timestamp('1960-1-1')
print(df['DATE'])
```

Should be

```
0   1959-12-22
2   1959-12-27
4   1960-01-01
6   1960-01-06
8   1960-01-11
Name: DATE, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Just looked at my data, and apparently it is a problem with all of the negative  values since they are all the same. so the problem is occuring way before I even do anything with the conversion